# Unable to launch emulator in Android Studio (error: Loading Devices)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a new PC and cloned my Android git repo to my device.

When I open my Android projects that are cloned from Git, I'm unable to launch the emulator. It shows "Add Configuration..." and "Loading Devices...".

[image]

However, when I created a new project from scratch on my new machine, the buttons work fine

[image]

I suppose it has something to do with my configuration files in the projects from Git, but I'm not sure what it is.

I don't have Flutter installed. I also noticed there's a missing module.

None of these worked:

- [Open as "Import Project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558671/android-studio-cant-see-device-in-a-specific-project)
- [Run as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290134/android-studio-avd-manager-button-is-disabled/41290210#41290210)
- [Invalidate Caches / Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101178/android-studio-device-list-stuck-on-loading/62084448#62084448)
- [Killed and restart adb process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101178/android-studio-device-list-stuck-on-loading/65612734#65612734)
- [Deleted and re-downloaded platform-tools](https://superuser.com/questions/1401980/android-studio-device-dropdown-stuck-on-loading/1618631#1618631)
- Deleted the .idea directory

Comment: Delete the `.idea` directory, when it's present in the repository.

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized settings.gradle was missing because of .gitignore when cloning to the new device. After commenting out the exclusion in .gitignore and recloning the repo, it works.